# Solved - QGIS Measurement

Tags: qgis, measurements

Solved.

In QGIS I turned off CRS. It then read the data of the image correctly.

I have brought a tiff photo of a side of a building into qGIS. It is about 300 images that were put together in Pix4d to an orthomosaic. When I took the photo I marked off 5m segments on the building with tape.

When I use the "Measure" tool in QGIS between the tape marks I get about 553,000 meters.

Is there an easy way to calibrate the measure tool to a known distance in the photo? I'd like to calibrate it and then use the measure tool to measure other things.

The reason I'm doing this is that I need to share the photo with someone, and I'd like them to be able to do measurements on the photo. QGIS seemed an ok way to do this.

Comment: I dont think QGIS is the right tool for this (unless this is an orthorectified aerial photo). But you could still made a ratio between 5m and 553 and use it on your other measurement

Comment: Hi - thanks J.R. It is an orthomosaic that was generated in Pix4d, so I think it is an orthorectified image?

Comment: What CRS are you using?

Comment: WGS 84  I think is the answer to that question.